# Installed firebase emulators, but it's not work and still require installation

Tags: firebase

Obviously I used to do the following:

```sh
$ firebase login
$ firebase init
$ firebase init emulators

...skip

i  Port for functions already configured: 5001
i  Port for firestore already configured: 8080
i  Port for database already configured: 9000
i  Port for hosting already configured: 5000
i  Port for pubsub already configured: 8085
i  Emulator UI already enabled with port: (automatic)
? Would you like to download the emulators now? Yes
i  ui: downloading ui-v1.4.1.zip...

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

✔  Firebase initialization complete!
```

But when I try `firebase emulators:start --only hosting:my_project_target_name`, I get the following message.

```sh
$ firebase emulators:start --only hosting:my_project_target_name
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.

Error: No emulators to start, run firebase init emulators to get started.
```

My development environment is as follows.

- nodejs: v12.20.1
- firebase: v9.3.0
- java: openjdk v1.8.0_275
- os: ubuntu 20.04

I tried again after `sudo su` but the result was the same.
What should I do?

---

add contents.

It only works when:

```sh
$ sudo firebase emulators:start --only hosting

i  emulators: Starting emulators: hosting
...
hosting[TARGET_NAME_!]: Local server: http://localhost:5000
...
hosting[TARGET_NAME_2]: Local server: http://localhost:5005
```

I only want to test hosting one project.

Comment: Did you make changes in your `firebase.json` file, Please read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites?authuser=0#define_hosting_config) doc before using that command

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
Of course I set it.
`firebase deploy --only hosting:TARGET_NAME` works fine.